# Как с помощью PHP выбрать два последних input?

Tags: php, sql

```
<form action="update.php"> 
   <input name=value[1]>
    <input name=value[2]>
    <input name=value[3]>
    <input name=value[4]>
    <input name=value[]>
    <input name=value[]>
</form>
```

Как с помощью PHP выбрать два последних input? при учете что цифры это id из таблицы БД

```
$index = array_keys($_POST['value']);
foreach ($index AS $item)
{
    $qty=$_POST['value'][$item];
    $update= $GLOBALS['pdo']->prepare("UPDATE test SET name = :value WHERE id = :id");
    $update->bindParam(':value', $qty);
    $update->bindParam(':id', $item);
    $update->execute();
}
```

код обрабатывающий input

Приведу еще дополнение. после запроса в БД в окне браузера отображается форма с заполненными полями (input), где [1] и т.д - это id записи из таблицы БД. (т.е цифра подставляется сама). 
Input же с пустым [] - это input, ктр пользователь добавляет по клику на кнопку"add". он может заполнять / не заполнять их-(как ему угодно). т.е повторюсь: после сохранения и последующего вывода цифра добавится.

Суть моей проблемы состоит в том чтобы при сохранении формы в таблицу БД попадали эти новые поля (поле) со значениями или без. Минуя копирование уже существующих полей формы.

Comment: Если там нет значений и они полностью идентичны, то тут можно через js, jquery. Устроит?

Comment: Простите, а что в PHP подразумевается под "**выбрать**"?

Comment: @ Denis640Kb. Там есть значения. они разные

Comment: @ВЛ80, как работать именно с двумя последними?  мне нужно чтобы только эти  два значения в инпутах сохранялись в таблицу БД

Comment: А вы можете привести пример кода, обрабатывающего данные из этих input?

Comment: @ВЛ80, отредактировал в основном сообщении

Comment: Судя по этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010970/1418463), поля с `[]` парсятся в один массив. Предполагаю, что в вашем случае вы можете получить к ним доступ так: `$_POST['value'][0]` - предпоследнее поле, и `$_POST['value'][1]` - последнее.

Comment: @ВЛ 80 почти. Только это первые 2 поля.

Comment: @Denis640Kb. Понял. А вообще, правильным решением было бы дать этим полям вменяемые имена и не изобретать велосипед. А если всё-таки очень хочется, то можно сделать `print_r(var_dump($_POST['value']))` и посмотреть что и как приходит.

Comment: @ВЛ80 . Да поля вроде названы адекватно. Это я в примере здесь заменил их название

Comment: Если ваша проблема всё ещё не решена, то советую добавить `print_r(var_dump($_POST));` в ваш скрипт, отправить форму и посмотреть на структуру данных в массиве `$_POST`. Можете также добавить эту информацию в вопрос, чтобы другие могли видеть.

Comment: @ВЛ80,Спасибо , добавлю

Answer (score 1):

Можно так получить эти значения:

```
<body>
    <form name="form" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name=value[1]>
        <input name=value[2]>
        <input name=value[3]>
        <input name=value[4]>
        <input name=value[]>
        <input name=value[]>
        <button name="123" id="123" formmethod="post">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

```php
if (isset($_POST["123"])) { //Где "123" - имя кнопки отправки формы.
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $num=count($_POST['value']);
        $last1 = array_pop($_POST['value']); // Последний элемент
        unset($_POST['value'][$num]);
        $last2 = array_pop($_POST['value']);// Предпоследний элемент
    } else {
        echo 'Данные не введены';
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведу еще дополнение. после запроса в БД в окне браузера отображается форма с заполненными полями (input), где [1] и т.д - это id записи из таблицы БД. (т.е цифра подставляется сама). Input же с пустым [] - это input, ктр пользователь добавляет по клику на кнопку"add". он может заполнять / не заполнять их-(как ему угодно). т.е повторюсь: после сохранения и последующего вывода цифра добавится.

Суть моей проблемы состоит в том чтобы при сохранении формы в таблицу БД попадали эти новые поля (поле) со значениями или без. Минуя копирование уже существующих полей формы.

Comment: Если новые input всегда в конце масива, можно вытащить их функцией array_slice.В качестве offset передаём количество стартовых полей (получаемых из БД).

Comment: Ещё вариант (подходит, даже если новые input расставляются случайным образом): для новых input используйте не value, а любое другое имя массива, например arr. Тогда после отправки формы у вас старые и новые поля будут в двух разных подмассивах $_POST.

Comment: Третий вариант (тоже со случайной расстановкой): не передавайте id из таблицы в качестве id в форме. Замените на любой строковый ключ или добавьте символов к id, чтобы получилась строка. Например 'old'+id. Тогда после отправки формы, все элементы с числовыми ключами - это новые поля, а со строковыми - старые. Если id из таблицы очень нужен для JS-кода - используйте data-атрибуты.

Comment: nikita888 Изначально в вопросе, Вы абсолютно конкретно указали, что хотите получить именно последние 2 записи, на что Вам дан был конкретный ответ. Формулируйте свой вопрос правильно, если хотите чтобы Вам помогли. Советую тогда Вам прежде изучить основы формирования форм в php, прежде чем выполнять задачи. Ответ @Ищу PHP-разработчика Волгоград абсолютно корректен.

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете это в качестве массива `$_POST` или `$_GET`. Теоретически, если сортировки не проводятся, то нужные значения будут либо в конце, либо в начале массива.

Можно выбрать так, если я правильно понял:

```
$_POST[count($_POST) - 1]; 
$_POST[count($_POST) - 2]
```